# duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate.class

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, parse-platform

I am getting the following error when I try to execute my app.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate.class
```

I believe that this error has something to do with my gradle file which is as follows

```
enandroid {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nirmal.sportsparse"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

I get the above mentioned error if I include multidex support
If I disable it I get the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

What is the reason for this and how can I resolve this???